# Division in JavaScript of two fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript. I've been following a tutorial on how to create a e-commerce website. In it, you're shown how to create a dashboard, which shows data about the website. Some of the things it lists are the number of orders (`numOrders`) and the total number of sales (`totalSales`). I would like to calculate the average number of sales (`averageSales`). However, I am having some difficulty. I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

```
   orderRouter.get(
    '/summary',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const orders = await Order.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            numOrders: { $sum: 1 },
            totalSales: { $sum: '$totalPrice' },
            averageSale: { $sum: '$totalPrice'/numOrders },
          },
        },
      ]);
      const users = await User.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            numUsers: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ]);
      const dailyOrders = await Order.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$createdAt' } },
            orders: { $sum: 1 },
            sales: { $sum: '$totalPrice' },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
      ]);
      const productCategories = await Product.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$category',
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ]);
      res.send({ users, orders, dailyOrders, productCategories });
    })
  );
```

Comment: _I am having some difficulty._ Please detail the issues. Without a [mcve] it is hard to guess what your difficulty could be